What is the $ \theta' $ means in Kepler problem in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics?
In Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, 3 edition, equation 3.50 is
\begin{align*}
 \theta=\theta^{\prime}-\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{l^2}+\frac{2mku}{l^2}-u^2}}\tag{3.50}
\end{align*}
I think $ \theta' $ is a appropriate constant of integration. But in Eq 3.100
\begin{align*}
 \frac1r=\frac{mZZ^{\prime}e^2}{l^2}(\epsilon\cos\theta-1)\tag{3.100}
\end{align*}
where $ \epsilon $ is eccentricity. It choose $ \theta' = \pi $, and let polar axis is the line connecting the center of force and the pericenter. So what is the mean of $ \theta' = \pi $?

I think in this context, you would express the differential element of $\theta$ as $\mathrm{d}\theta=\theta’-\theta$, but I could be mistaken. The prime of a variable often refers to another “instance” of that variable in texts I read and write.
